# Replace all boolean values in a dict by a corresponding value without looping through dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, shorthand

I have the following dict:

```
d = {
    "one": False,
    "two": True,
    "three": False,
    "four": True,
    "five": False
    }
```

I want to **replace** each instance of `True` by `"Hello"` and each instance of `False` by `Good night`.

In the end, I want the following dict:

```
d = {
    "one": "Good night",
    "two": "Hello",
    "three": "Good night",
    "four": "Hello",
    "five": "Good night"
    }
```

Is there a way to do it **without** a for loop, or without iterating each value?

*Edit: I can still use a for, I just want to know if there's a shorter way to do it than a for block. Also I wanted to know if there was a shorthand to "map" booleans to values in a dicitonary.*

I can't manage to do it without browsing/looping through each key/value of the dict. Based on other answers, I tried this: `d = d.update( (k,"Hello") for k in d )` but this is for replacing *all* values, and not on a condition.

Comment: You're trying to do something to every element in a dictionary. I don't know how you expect that to be possible without some iteration somewhere. I'd be absolutely shocked if this could be done in less than O(n).

Comment: @ScienceSnake He means an explicit loop, as opposed to calling a function that processes the dict in one call.

Comment: Yes sorry, explicit loop. I just want to avoid having a large for block. Editing the question

Comment: @C.Crt Define "large" for block.

Comment: lazy evaluation: wrap it in a custom dict which adapts True to "Hello", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it without a loop.

```
for key, val in d.items():
    d[key] = "Hello" if val else "Good night"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a different data structure in constant time that has the same effect:

```
def lazy_converted(dct):
    class D(dict):
        def __getitem__(self, k):
            if k in dct:
                if dct[k] is True:
                    return "Hello"
                if dct[k] is False:
                    return "Good night"
                return dct[k]
            return super().__getitem__(k)
    return D()

>>> d = lazy_converted(d)
>>> d["one"]
'Good night'
>>> d["two"]
'Hello'
```

Note that `d` is still a `dict`, the conversion involves no iteration whatsoever and happens in constant time and you can still set new keys:

```
>>> d["acd"] = 5
>>> d["acd"]
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to check every key, it will not be faster than O(n)

```
>>> d = {
...     "one": False,
...     "two": True,
...     "three": False,
...     "four": True,
...     "five": False
...     }
>>> 
>>> replacement = {False:'Good night', True:'Hello'}
>>> d = {k:replacement.get(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'one': 'Good night', 'two': 'Hello', 'three': 'Good night', 'four': 'Hello', 'five': 'Good night'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a generator like:

```py
d = {
    "one": False,
    "two": True,
    "three": False,
    "four": True,
    "five": False
    }
d.update((k, "Hello" if d[k] else "Good night") for k in d.keys())
print(d)
# {'one': 'Good night', 'two': 'Hello', 'three': 'Good night', 'four': 'Hello', 'five': 'Good night'}
```

As mentioned in the comments, though, this is not faster than a regular for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can, but not sure why you would:

```
>>> choices = ('Good Night', 'Hello')
>>> *_, = map(lambda x,y: dict.update(d, {x:choices[y]}), d.keys(), d.values())
>>> d
{'one': 'Good Night',
 'two': 'Hello',
 'three': 'Good Night',
 'four': 'Hello',
 'five': 'Good Night'}
```

Rather sweet dict comprehension:

```
>>> choices = ('Hello', 'Good Night')
>>> d = {k: choices[v] for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'one': 'Good Night',
 'two': 'Hello',
 'three': 'Good Night',
 'four': 'Hello',
 'five': 'Good Night'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without using any loops I think is the following method.
In this method, we use the json library so we can convert the dictionary into a string, then replacing the values, and finally turn it into a dictionary again.

```
import json

d = {
    "one": False,
    "two": True,
    "three": False,
    "four": True,
    "five": False
    }  
       
# Serializing json    
d = json.dumps(d)   

# Replace true by "Hello"
d = d.replace('true', '"Hello"')
    
# Replace false by "Good night"
d = d.replace('false', '"Good night"')

# Convert string to dictionary
d = json.loads(d)

print(d)
```